# C Programming w/Pipes prints weirdly to STDOUT

Tags: c, pipe, exec, fork

I'm working on a programming assignment for my Operating Systems class and I'm running into some issues with the way my output is showing up in the terminal.

The purpose of the program is to take input from a file or the STDIN and essentially pass it through 4 pipes to get the frequency of the words. I'm using calls to fork(),execlp(), and pipe() to complete this and am not having any issues with my program, however as the last child executes and prints to the terminal it looks like this:

```
os-class ~/cs344/Homework3 190% myword text.txt  
os-class ~/cs344/Homework3 191%       1 aaaaa        
1 aaaaaa      
  1 aaaaaaa  
      8 it  
      5 s  
      5 sa
```

(Here I could enter command for 191%, something like 'ls'..)

myword is my executable and text.txt is the file I'm using for testing. I'm mainly confused because it seems like my pipes are lined up correctly with STDIN and STDOUT. Do I need to insert a `wait()` somewhere?

Thanks for any suggestions and sorry if there's already an answer to this somewhere! I wasn't exactly sure what to search for.

Comment: Yes, you probably do need to use a `wait()` (or perhaps several `wait()` calls, maybe in a loop) to ensure that all the output appears before `myword` exits.

Answer (score 0):

Each parent that does `fork()` will need to `wait()` on its children or the children will continue to run after the parent has exited.

The shell (if you wrote it) also needs to wait on the programs it starts.

Comment: All of my knowledge is coming out of the book The Linux Programming Interface, all of their wait() calls are wait(NULL)...in my case do I need to replace NULL with the childs return status?

Comment: @TonyTyrrell: If you want to know the exit status of a child, then yes, you do need to use something like: `int corpse; int status; corpse = wait(&status);` to get which process died (the corpse) and the exit status.  If you have processes running in background, they may die when you're expecting some other process to die, so you usually need to `wait()` in a loop, or use `waitpid()`, or both.